# Do we have $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Q)$ for the generated $\sigma$-algebras?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $Q=\left\{Q_1: i=1,2,\ldots,N\right\}$ is a finite partition of $X$, i.e. $X=\biguplus_{i=1}^NQ_i$, i.e., $X$ is a disjoint union of the $Q_i$.

Is it true that $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Q)$?

First of all, we have that $Q\subset X$, hence $\sigma(Q)\subset\sigma(X)$, isn't it?

Next, we have that $Q\subset\sigma(Q)$. But if $Q$ is contained in $\sigma(Q)$ then also $\bigcup_{i=1}^NQ_i$ by definition of a $\sigma$-algebra. But this means that $X\subset \sigma(Q)$, hence $\sigma(X)\subset \sigma(\sigma(Q))=\sigma(Q)$.

Hence $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Q)$. Am I correct?

Comment: What is $\sigma(X)$?

Comment: It is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $X$.

Comment: Why did somebody suggest to close this question? What is wrong about it?

Comment: $Q$ is a subset of the power set of $X$, while $X$ is only an element of that power set, to it's false that $Q \subset X$. Your next paragraph is correct, it does indeed follow like you reasoned that $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Q)$, but be careful: $\sigma(X)$ can only mean the sigma algebra generated by the set containing only $X$ as an element (so it is in fact the smallest possible sigma algebra on the power set of $X$).

Comment: If by $\sigma(X)$ you mean the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $X$, that is  $\sigma(\{X\})$,  then  $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Comment: The only situation where $\sigma(Q)\subset\sigma(X)$ would be true is if $Q$ is the trivial partition $Q=\left\{X\right\}$. Then, $\sigma(Q)= \sigma(\{X\})= \sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,X\}$.

Comment: No I got it. Thanks